# calculate milliseconds from the mid night

Tags: c++, c, unix, unix-timestamp

I need to calculate the milliseconds from the mid night, written the code but seems there is any problem.

```
 time_t t;
 time_t rawtime;
 char buff[256] ={0};
 struct timeval tv;
 struct timezone tz;
 struct tm *tma;

 gettimeofday(&tv, &tz);
 tma=localtime(&tv.tv_sec);
 static char* months[] = {"JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY","JUN","JUL","AUG","SEP","OCT","NOV","DEC"};
 sprintf(buff,"%02d %s %d 00:00:00",tma->tm_mday, months[tma->tm_mon], tma->tm_year + 1900);

 struct tm tm1;
 strptime(buff, "%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S", &tm1);
 tm1.tm_isdst = -1;
 t = mktime(&tm1);
 time ( &rawtime );

time_t milSecFromMidNight = (rawtime  - t)*1000 +  tv.tv_usec/1000;
```

It seems some time there is differences in milliseconds. Anyone can point out it?

Comment: When you say differences, what problem are you seeing?

Comment: sometime its millisecond is less than as expected

Answer (score 2):

You need to correctly calculate, as a time_t, the last previous midnight, that is, the midnight at which the current day began. You can do it something like this:

```
// function to calculate midnite last night

time_t  // calc current day 00:00:00
today_at_0000 ( ) {
  time_t curtime, midtime;
  struct tm *localtm_p;
  curtime = time( NULL );
  localtm_p = localtime( &curtime );
  localtm_p->tm_hour = 0;
  localtm_p->tm_min = 0;
  localtm_p->tm_sec = 0;
  midtime = mktime( localtm_p ); // today at 00:00:00
  return midtime;
}
```

The important point is you have to use mktime( ) to find midnight after setting tm_hour, tm_min, and tm_sec of the current time to zero.

You know what to do after you find the time_t of midnight.

Comment: i am looking milliseconds not in seconds.

Comment: @CrazyC -- Wow, that's a tough one! You certainly know how to pose a challenge. I'll have to think about it. Oh, yeah! Now I remember: milliseconds = seconds * 1000. Whew! don't ask these mind-bending questions anymore -- all that thinking makes my head explode :-)

Comment: I am looking time in millisecond precisely. If I convert seconds into millisecond then will loss the milliseconds. Lets assume, the moment i am rieving the time is 2:30:07:499(h:mm:ss:millisecond), as per the proposed solution I will lose 499 millisecond.  Hope you got the point :)

Comment: Oh, I see, thanks. That is accounted for when you calculate the time_t for midnight. Midnight is hour0, minute0, second0, millisecond0 is 0:0:0:0, correct? In other words, when you form the time_t of midnight you are only interested in the beginning of the day; the hour, minute, second, and millisecond are not part of the calculation -- they are thrown away, set to zero -- so you don't lose anything.

Comment: Could you please post the code? struct tm don't have any member variable for milliseconds.

Comment: I did post the code. Milliseconds becomes zero when you set seconds to zero. See, you are the one who is *constructing* or *developing* milliseconds when you get to the point where you need it. You are, in a sense, *inventing* the milliseconds part.

Comment: Let's do it this way: First, find the difference between "now" and midnight in ***seconds***. Then, take that difference and multiply it by 1000 to give you that difference in ***milliseconds***. Then, to that result, add your incremental milliseconds. I think it was 499 before. The sum is the elapsed time since midnight in milliseconds. How does that sound to you? I can promise you that it's the correct way to do it.